# Rotate catalina.out with rotatelogs?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to rotate catalina.out when it surpasses a maximum size on a dedicated security appliance that I help develop. We currently use logrotate for this task, but I am trying to make the file rotate immediately when it hits the size limit instead of relying on a daily cron job.

According to [the Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q10), I should try patching catalina.sh to pipe output to a command, [like so](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53930). We don't have cronolog on this appliance, but we do have httpd so I decided to use `rotatelogs`:

```
CATALINA_OUT_CMD="/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f $CATALINA_OUT 100M >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

The problem is that catalina.out isn't even created there. What should I do?

Here is the part of *my* version of the patch file that enables piping to commands:

```
@@ -33,6 +33,13 @@
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out
#
+#   CATALINA_OUT_CMD (Optional) Command which will be executed and receive
+#                   as its stdin the stdout and stderr from the Tomcat java
+#                   process.  Only used if CATALINA_OUT is not defined.
+#                   No default.
+#                   Example (all one line)
+#                   CATALINA_OUT_CMD="cronolog $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.%Y-%m-%d.out >/dev/null 2>&1"
+#
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
#                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
@@ -367,13 +374,22 @@ elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then
fi

shift
-  touch "$CATALINA_OUT"
+  if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT_CMD" ] ; then
+    catalina_out_command=">> \"$CATALINA_OUT\" 2>&1"
+  else
+    catalina_out_command="| $CATALINA_OUT_CMD"
+  fi
+  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
+    catalina_pid_file="$CATALINA_PID"
+  else
+    catalina_pid_file=/dev/null
+  fi
if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
echo "Using Security Manager"
fi
shift
-    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
+    eval \{ "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
-Djava.security.manager \
-Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
@@ -381,21 +397,17 @@ elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then
-Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
-Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
-      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
+      2\>\&1 \& echo \$! \>\"$catalina_pid_file\" \; \} $catalina_out_command "&"

else
-    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
+    eval \{ "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
-Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
-Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
-Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
-      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
-
-  fi
+      2\>\&1 \& echo \$! \>\"$catalina_pid_file\" \; \} $catalina_out_command "&"

-  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
-    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
fi

echo "Tomcat started."
```

P.S. In case it matters, I am testing rotation with the following, modified "out command" so that I don't have to wait as long for the log to fill up:

```
CATALINA_OUT_CMD="/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f $CATALINA_OUT 1M >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

P.P.S. I would be willing to try log4j again if you guys ask me to, but I failed to get that working last time I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I don't know of a way to force rotation at a certain filesize. Which makes sense as it means an application would have to be constantly running and checking... but, you can just increase how often logrotate runs and set size limits. If it runs every 15 minutes, with a maximum allowed size of 50MB, then at most it can only go over 50 MB for 15 minutes.

You can set how often it runs in cron.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your math at the end there (what if there is a massive dump to the log that is 100 MB or something?) but I think I may resort to that. You sure there isn't something that can be done with log4j?

Comment: Restated math: "it can only go over the limit for 15 min" cant say for log4j; I can say that you can just write a script to check it every minute (or second), and then force log rotate. Shouldn't take too many resources to just run a "ls -l' on your file and write an 'if' function for it's size."  As a sort of related answer, I can say that I've got enterprise experience with Catalina logging. And they can get huge, but after a week or two, you always sort of know what the pattern its going to be so logrotate can be set up properly. Unless a dev sets it to "debug and forgets...," lol.